# Awk syntax error in loop

Tags: shell, awk

```
cat file1
xi=zaoshui jiao=@E0488_5@
chi=fan da qiu=@E0488_3@
gong=zuo you xi @E0977_5@

cat file2
@E0488_3@ @E21562_3@
@E0488_5@ @E21562_5@
@E0977_3@ @E21630_3@
@E0977_5@ @E21630_5@
@E0977_6@ @E21631_1@
```

Purpose: if $NF in file1 found in file2 $1, than replace $NF in file1 with file2 $2.otherwise, makes no change.

My Code:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}
     {split($NF,a,"=");for($NF in a){$NF=a[$NF]}}1' test2.txt test1.txt
```

But it comes error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{split($NF,a,"=");for($NF in a){$NF=a[$NF]}}1
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                     ^ syntax error
```

Does my code look right? It seems grammar issue happens. How can I improve it?

My expect output:

```
   xi=zaoshui jiao=@E21562_5@
   chi=fan da qiu=@E21562_3@
   gong=zuo you xi @E21630_5@
```

Comment: You can't use `$NF` as the loop variable. I guess you want `for (x in a){$x=a[x]}` but it's not really clear. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: thank you . sorry for the inconvenience , I have update my question

Comment: @Sundeepyou are right, I change `if` instead of `for`,but the output makes no change compared with the original file1, why ? ` awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{split($NF,a,"=");if($NF in a){$NF=a[$NF]}}1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `for($NF in a)` is not valid syntax, (`$NF` gives value)

it can be like

```
for (var in array)
    body
```

Read More from : [GNU AWK Scanning-an-Array](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Scanning-an-Array.html#Scanning-an-Array)

- Used `sub($NF,a[$NF])` to retain your original field separator, since last record, last field has space before, whereas other lines last field has `=` before, assuming values doesn't repeat other than last field.

Test Results:

```
$ cat file1
xi=zaoshui jiao=@E0488_5@
chi=fan da qiu=@E0488_3@
gong=zuo you xi @E0977_5@

$ cat file2
@E0488_3@ @E21562_3@
@E0488_5@ @E21562_5@
@E0977_3@ @E21630_3@
@E0977_5@ @E21630_5@
@E0977_6@ @E21631_1@

$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$NF;next}($NF in a){sub($NF,a[$NF])}1' file2 FS='[ =]' file1
xi=zaoshui jiao=@E21562_5@
chi=fan da qiu=@E21562_3@
gong=zuo you xi @E21630_5@
```

Comment: Thanks, it is really great. but one more question, when I changed the `FS='[ =]'` with `FS='='` in your code , the output changed  as not I expect. So, could you please make it more clear about separator for `FS='[ =]'` ?

Comment: @huangcheng with `FS='[ =]'` you are telling awk that, field separator being either space or `=`, I made it because of your last line, otherwise awk will treat last field for last record (`$NF =>  zuo you xi @E21630_5@`), if you just set `FS='='`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure completely but could you please try following and do let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$NF;next} ($NF in a){$NF=a[$NF]} 1' FS="=" file2 FS='[= ]' OFS="=" file1
```

Output will be as follows.

```
xi=zaoshui jiao=@E0488_5@
chi=fan da qiu=@E0488_3@
gong=zuo you xi @E0977_5@
```

***EDIT:*** Adding explanation too now for same.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{                               ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file named file2 is being read.
  a[$1]=$NF;                           ##making an array named a whose index is $1 of current line and value is last field of the current line.
  next                                 ##next will skip all the further statements now.
}
($NF in a){                            ##Checking condition here if last field of current line of Input_file file1 is present in array a if yes then do following.
  $NF=a[$NF]                           ##creating last field value to array a value whose index is $NF of current line in Input_file file1.
}
1                                      ##1 will print the lines for Input_file file1.
' FS="=" file2 FS='[= ]' OFS="=" file1 ##Setting FS="=" for file2 and setting FS value to either = or space for file1 and setting OFS value to = for file1 too.
```

Comment: yes. it seems makes no change, I have update my question

Comment: @huangcheng, have changed my code accordingly now, let me know if that helps you.

Comment: yes ，it works, could you please make it clear for separator `FS='[= ]'` mean?

Comment: @huangcheng, added explanation now for my code please have a look to it and let me know if this helps you.,

Comment: no need `OFS="="` in your code , thus may separate each line with `=`

Comment: really appreciate for your explanation~

Answer (score 2):

My code is as below, hope it could be helpful even if it's not the most efficient answer.

```
awk '$NF ~ /=/ {gsub("="," @ ",$NF)}{print $0}' file1 > file3
cat file3
xi=zaoshui jiao @ @E0488_5@
chi=fan da qiu @ @E0488_3@
gong=zuo you xi @E0977_5@
```

As you said ,replace file1 with file3, if $NF of file3 found in file2 $1, than replace $NF of file3 with file2 $2

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;next}($NF in a){$NF=a[$NF]}1' file2 file3 | sed 's/ @ /=/g'
xi=zaoshui jiao=@E21562_5@
chi=fan da qiu=@E21562_3@
gong=zuo you xi @E21630_5@
```